# Subdirectories under "branches"

Tags: svn, repository

Is it possible to create a subdirectory under "branches", and then place copies below that?

For example:

```
branches/user69/project-1, branches/user69/project-2, branches/user42/xyz-bugs
```

I tried `svn mkdir` but it didn't work. It came back with:

```
A    https://example.com/svn/blah/branches/user69
```

But it did not in fact create a subdirectory on the repo (nor local disk).

I am sure I have seen this kind of SVN hierarchy, but there must be a trick to it.

I also just tried:

```
svn copy http://example.com/blah/trunk http://example.com/blah/branches/user69/project-1
```

But that didn't work either:

```
Path not found.
```

Comment: you might want to reconsider a non-standard repo layout. what would be the problem of making /branches/user69-project1.  Everyone's IDEs won't understand your structure.  Your peers will likely dislike it, and a guarantee your successors will be sad at you.

Answer (score 0):

There are no tricks that I notice. I just did it on the command line with no problems. The only thing you didn't mention was committing your changes after the svn mkdir command. If you are still having a problem, can you post the exact commands you are inputting (obviously changing your actual svn repo to https://example.com when pasting)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have any tree structure inside repository - it's just a matter of convention for team

> "A https://example.com/svn/blah/branches/user69"

means, that you **created really** *user69* version-controlled subdir under /branches, can relocate WC and commit, using this URL

If you wanted to create branches/USERNAME/BRANCHNAME **in one command**, while /USERNAME still doesn't exist, you must to use option --parents in `svn mkdir`, see `svn help mkdir`

> ...all the intermediate directories must already exist,  unless the --parents option is given.

Comment: My problem was that it tried to run Emacs for the checkin message, and that failed and wrote the "A ..." in an "svn-commit.3.tmp" file and returned code 256.   In other words, it did not commit.  Running a second commit command for some reason did not work.   But if I just issue the command in the first place with the "-m" option, it works, gives me a revision number, and the "ls" command will then show it.